# How can read in pictures and view them using a button Delphi

Tags: delphi

I know how to load and view one picture in delphi. However I would like to add a 'next image' button that brings up the next image in the file. I have 5 images in a file and i would like to scroll through them easily using a next button! I have tried to make the next button, But have no idea what code to put in!

Please help thanks.

Gpath is a global string variable.

```
procedure TPropertyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GPath := getcurrentdir + '\EmployeePhotos\';
  EmployeeOpenPictureDialog.InitialDir := getcurrentdir + '\EmployeePhotos';

end;

procedure TPropertyForm.AttatchButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  st: string;
  fsize, psize: integer;
begin
  if EmployeeOpenPictureDialog.execute then
  begin
    st := EmployeeOpenPictureDialog.FileName;
    psize := length(GPath);
    fsize := length(st);
    Properties.Photo := copy(st, psize + +1, fsize - psize)
  end { endif };

  PhotoImage.Hide;

  if Properties.Photo <> '' then
  begin
    st := GPath + Properties.Photo;
    if FileExists(st) then
    begin
      PhotoImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(st);
      PhotoImage.Proportional := true;
      PhotoImage.Show;
    end
    { endif }
  end; { endif }
end

procedure TPropertyForm.NextImageButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PhotoImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(st + 1);
end;
```

Comment: Did you try use the ImageList component?

Comment: Your code won't compile. Do you know the name of the image files? Don't rely on the current directory being what you think it is.

Comment: You have 5 images in a single file?  What kind of file is it?  Delphi image classes do not natively support multi-image files, so you are going to have to do some extra work to process and separate out the multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to load images from "Folder" and switch between them, if so try this code

place 2 TButtons and 1 TImage

```
         uses jpeg;
public
{ Public declarations }
var
SL:TStringList;
ImgIndex:integer;
GPath:String;
procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(Path + '*.jpg', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then 
  begin
    repeat
  if (SR.Attr <> faDirectory) then
      begin
        FileList.Add(SR.Name);
      end;
    until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
    FindClose(SR);
  end;
end;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
GPath:=   getcurrentdir + '\EmployeePhotos\';
SL:=TStringList.Create;
ListFileDir(GPath,SL);
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(GPath + SL.Strings[ImgIndex] );
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNextClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ImgIndex:=ImgIndex+1;
if ImgIndex=SL.Count  then ImgIndex :=0;
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(GPath + SL.Strings[ImgIndex] );
end;

procedure TForm1.btnPrevClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ImgIndex:=ImgIndex-1;
if ImgIndex=-1  then ImgIndex :=SL.Count-1;
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(GPath + SL.Strings[ImgIndex] );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
SL.Free;
end;
```